how this expression with stdin exactly works?
why echo p | passwd --stdin password while just passwd --stdin password (without pipeline) doesn't work?
Why do we need echo p here?

Because otherwise you are not going to see what is passed hence the echo. I don’t understand the question. It doesn’t print something because it’s not supposed to without a pipe out of an echo command

passwd takes the login (username) as the first argument, not the password itself. The pipe | connects echos stdout to the stdin of passwd. For example: echo -n "newpassword" | sudo passwd --stdin username.

Which version of passwd do you use?
